# Create-React-App .env file directory location (Non-root)

Tags: reactjs, express, environment-variables, create-react-app, dotenv

After creating a new web app with `create-react-app (CRA)`, I need to include some environment files for configuring various endpoints.  Noticed that CRA comes with the cool `dotenv` package all ready to go.  There's only one problem with that - I would like to have `dotenv` read these files from within my `./environments` directory and not the root directory.  Is there any way to load the `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.test`, etc... files in a directory *separate* from the root directory?

Noticing I can achieve this in my express backend `server.js` by simply importing like so:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `./environments/` })
```

Can I do the same with my client-side code in React?  If so, where should I put this import?  Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You can [check this](https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37)

Answer (score 8):

If you created your project using CRA and want to configure [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to change the path from where it loads the [env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) files, you will have to do [npm eject](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html#no-lock-in).

Alternatively, you can use [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) to achieve the same:

**Installation**:

```
npm i env-cmd
```

**Add scripts** in *package.json*, for example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    
    "dev": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.dev react-scripts build",
     "qa": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.qa react-scripts build",
    "demo": "env-cmd -f envs/.env.demo react-scripts build"
  },
```

After creating `.env.dev`, `.env.qa`, `.env.demo` in `envs/` directory.

Now, you can run:

```
$ npm run dev // it will use envs/.env.dev file
$ npm run qa // it will use envs/.env.qa file
$ npm run demo // it will use envs/.env.demo file
```

Comment: Correct, see:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/fddce8a9e21bf68f37054586deb0c8636a45f50b/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L86

For the hard-coded .env path relative to the package root.

This is not going to change by the looks of things https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1697

Which is a shame as react-scripts is essentially zero configuration for loading .envs in compound order